# Confusion about JVM args [-Xnoclassgc]

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

The arguments "-Xnoclassgc" forbid the GC collector unloading classes.
But there are constants in Perm Space.
So will the constants be collected by GC?If yes,does it mean that the GC will still scan the whole Perm Space?

Comment: All constants are part of the class that defines them, no?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with “constants”.

Comment: @Holger would you like to explain more?